# how the gcc -llibname and the OS find lib path?

Tags: linux, gcc

I had symbolic link to the target libs:

```
~/opt/OpenBLAS/lib $ ls -al
total 0
drwxrwxr-x 2 user user  59 Jul  9 13:03 .
drwxrwxr-x 5 user user 147 Jul  9 12:48 ..
lrwxrwxrwx 1 user user  64 Jul  9 13:03 libopenblas.a -> ../openBLAS_v0.2.9df/lib/libopenblas_df029_sandybridgep-r0.2.9.a
lrwxrwxrwx 1 user user  65 Jul  9 13:03 libopenblas.so -> ../openBLAS_v0.2.9df/lib/libopenblas_df029_sandybridgep-r0.2.9.so
```

$ echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH

```
/home/user/opt/OpenBLAS/lib
```

Then the gcc has following args:

```
-L/home/user/opt/OpenBLAS/lib -lopenblas
```

however, after compiling, run the command it always throws out error:

```
error while loading shared libraries: libopenblas_df029.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

If I create a symbolic link `libopenblas_df029.so.0` under the `/home/user/opt/OpenBLAS/lib`, it will then work.

Can anyone explain to me why this is happening and how can I change the behaviour?
Does this mean the libopenblas contain some suffix and the OS always append this suffix when trying to find lib file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, your library "libopenblas_df029_sandybridgep-r0.2.9.so" is compiled with "-soname" switch

something like:

```
gcc -shared -Wl,-soname,libopenblas_df029.so.0 source.c -o libopenblas_df029_sandybridgep-r0.2.9.so
```

When you link against such library, your executable tries to find library by name "libopenblas_df029.so.0" ( i.e. whatever name you specified in -soname switch )

The best way to find if this is true is to run following command and look for "SONAME"

```
readelf -d <shared_object> | head -10
```

Answer (score 0):

Like @Icarus3 said, the linked executable contains the name of the library as it wants to be called (the *SONAME*).

There should be a symbolic link from that name to the actual shared library. If it is missing, the library is not properly installed -- usually it is a sign that you need to run `ldconfig` to update the symbolic links and the dynamic linker cache.